# How do I solve many-to-many relationships when designing databases?

Tags: excel, database, powerbi, many-to-many, relationship

First time posting a question, here goes. I'm busy setting up a PowerBI presentation, and importing data from Excel Sheets. I'm doing environmental work, and so I need to relate projects occurring in a specific zone (from ZoneTbl) with activities (from ActTbl) occurring in that same zone. However, one zone can have multiple activities, and one activity can also be present in multiple zones. So the problem I'm having is defining many, many-to-many relationships between tables. I've tried "junction tables", where I have tried relating two foreign keys (in the form of the primary key from ZoneTbl, ZoneID, and the primary key from ActTbl, ActID). However, I still end up with some many-to-many relationships. I've been told this is poor databse modelling, and I'd like to do it correctly, and so any advice around defining these types of relationships, and specifically dealing with the problem of "zones having multiple activities and activities having multiple zones", would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Junction tables is the traditionl modeling solution. You'll ave two strong entities (zone, activity) and one weak entity (activity_in_a_zone). The latter will include the keys of the strong ones.

Comment: Agree with @TheImpaler, using coupling tables is the standard way to do it. What do you mean by "I still wind up with some many-to-many relationships? Isn't that what you want?

Comment: @ChristopherHamkins The questions I posted here was just an example from a database I'm making. I have many cases where many-to-many relationships pop up, not just with ZoneTbl and ActivityTbl. But will give this a shot and see how it goes! Thanks for the advice, and also thank you @TheImpaler!